# Converting text data into columns (excel)

Tags: excel, text

My data is in the following format :

```
Tin :   07020182045
Dealer Name :   VED RAM VEER SINGH
Dealer Address :C-195 GREATER KAILASH PART-I ,, NEW DELHI,
Ward :  88
Registration Type : VAT + CST
Return Frequency :  Quarterly
Status :    Cancelled
Registration Date : 01-04-2005

Tin :   07020202027
Dealer Name :   GURDEEP SINGH & SONS
Dealer Address :IX/2265 GALI NO 10 KAILASH NAGAR ,, NEW DELHI 110051,
Ward :  78
Registration Type : VAT + CST
Return Frequency :  Quarterly
Status :    Cancelled
Registration Date : 01-04-2005
```

Will it be possible to convert it from paragraph format to columns ?

Answer (score 0):

once you pasted your text into a column, you can go the menu item 'data' > text to columns > delimited > select 'other' and enter ":" without the quotes in the text box next to it. Then click finish and your text will now be in to columns.

if you need, you can also copy the columns and paste them transposed

Answer (score 0):

You can perform text to column on the data, using ':' as delimiter.  Text to column will then put tin in one column and 07020182045 in another column.

Comment: specifically in the case of `07020182045`, you should note, that if not formatted as text, the leading 0 may get lost... also should the text be "trimmed" or you may end up with lots of spaces ;)

Comment: I think changing the format of next 2 column to text   Before running text to column should help in preserving the zero values.